# Como selecionar vários?

Tags: php

Estou tentando atribuir nas[0] nas[1] nas[2] e nas[3] para a variável id... Como eu faço?

O que eu tentei fazer foi isso:

```
$id = $nas[0,1,2,3]
```

Comment: Explique melhor: você quer ter também `$id[0] ... $id[3]`? O que você vai fazer com o id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($nas); $i++) {
    $id = $nas[$i];
}
```

Comment: i deveria iniciar com 0 para percorrer todos elementos do array, ser enquanto for menor e não menor ou igual, e até count do nas, para não ficar limitado a pegar 3 itens.. -1

Comment: Kkkk Verdade, acabei dando uma errada ali mas já corrigi, Obrigado. Opinião pessoal: Só achei desnecessário ter tirado o ponto ali pois foi apenas um erro de digitação, mas enfim né?!.

Comment: É necessário o -1, não é nada pessoal mas sim de acordo com a qualidade da resposta, ainda pode melhorar colocando a condição como ‘$i < count($nas)` e eliminando a minha `i = 0;` porque além de ter erro de sintaxe é desnecessária. Mas valeu, por levar como critica construtiva mano, tem gente que não aceita

Comment: Editei a resposta, agora sim +1

Comment: Opa, Valeu cara kkkk.